# html5 audio control tag not working in mvc3 code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html

Here is my code:

```
<audio controls>                    
                    <source src="@Url.Action(@"C:\WS\Soongs\Soong\Content\themes\base\songs\Test.wma")" type="audio/mp3" />
                    <p>Your browser does not support HTML 5 audio element</p>
                </audio>
```

Audio is coming disabled? Can anyone please tell me how to fix this issue? Or what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link refers to a file on your local harddrive. That's not going to work.

Change `@Url.Action(...)` to `@Url.Content("~/example/test.wma")` and make sure the file is part of your project.

Comment: I tried using Content - But it still shows it disabled? Anything else i can try?

Comment: @NoviceMe It's not only the Content keyword you have to use. Don't use a local path that starts with C:\. Link to this file in the same way as with an image, script or css file on your site.

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio controls>
        <source src="@Url.Action("myaudio")" type="audio/mp3" />
        <p>Your browser does not support HTML 5 audio element</p></audio>
```

Where my "myaudio" is your file name with full path and extension.